# My header is in fixed position and i have a Disqus issue.

Tags: css, wordpress, html, position, disqus

**My Situation:**
I have a non moving header which stays in place whenever i scroll down. I have a div at the bottom just before the footer. This DIV contains the Disqus Commenting System.

**The problem is:**

whenever i scroll down at the bottom, the DIV run smoothly as expected (right under the Header) **BUT** the Disqus Commenting System GOES ABOVE the header which is supposed to be UNDER the header.

**The code of div and the call function of comments template is right down below:**

```
<div class="comments-template" style="position:inherit;">
<?php comments_template(); ?>
</div>
```

**The CSS Codes for DIV and Disqus Commenting System is  below:**

```
.comments-template{
    width: 1040px;
    position: static;
    margin: auto;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#CCC;

}

#disqus_thread {
    color: #FFF; 
    padding: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    clear:both;
    position:static;
}

.dsq-comment-header {
    background-color: 2d2d2d;
    font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 50px;
    position:static;
    clear:both;
    }

.dsq-comment-message {
    font-family:"Tahoma",sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333; 

    }
textarea {
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border:  #666 2px solid; /* light blue border */

    }
.dsq-comment {
    border: #666 2px solid; /* light blue border */
    margin-bottom: 15px;

    }
```

I hope you can help me with my problem.

**Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your header a higher `z-index`:

```
header {
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: No problem. Just a shot in the dark for me, as I have no idea what Disqus even is :P